# Bootstrap display errors on input-group wrapper?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to add an `input-addon` to a form input using Bootstrap 3 but it doesn't display the errros correctly. This is my html code:

```
<label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="addTax_rate" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
</div>
```

The input group displays correctly without errors, but when I add the has-errors class to it, it comes to this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Where are you adding the `has-error` class?  What browser are you viewing this in?

Comment: In Google Chrome, and I'm adding it to the input-group

Comment: That's odd...I literally copied and pasted your code into a blank page of my own, and everything works just fine.  What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: you must add the `has-error` class to a wrapper div

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.6 @DaveV

Comment: I tried to add the `has-error` class to a parent `form-group` and It doesn' work... @tmg

Comment: It does for me, check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxtjr39b/10/)

Comment: Ok, I now see what my error was. I was displaying the errors inside the input-group and not inside the form-group... Thanks @tmg